# Join information from 2 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I currently have 2 tables which hold information about an item. The first table shows various names for a given item no:

```
Item No   Name
1         Name1
1         Name2
1         Name3
```

The second table shows various locations for the given item no:

```
Item No  Location
1        Location1
1        Location2
```

I'm currently using the following statement to join these 2 tables

```
Select * 
from FirstTable a
Left Join 
(
   Select * 
   from SecondTable
) b 
   on a.itemno = b.itemno
```

I end up with this data:

```
Item No    Name       Location
1          Name1      Location1
1          Name1      Location2
1          Name2      Location1
1          Name2      Location2
1          Name3      Location1
1          Name3      Location2
```

What I would like to end up with is this:

```
Item No    Name       Location
1          Name1      Location1
1          Name2      Location2
1          Name3      NULL
```

How can I achieve the results I'm looking for?

Comment: All your items have the same No `1`. Is it correct? I suppose it is identifier, isn't it?

Comment: How should rows in the first table be associated with rows in the second? Table rows have no implicit ordering, so you'll need to apply some explicit ordering for the join.

Comment: is "Item No" primary key?

Comment: Yes, ItemNo is the identifier. There are no rules to how the two tables should be joined: they should be treated as independent rows simply showing up in the same table. ItemNo is the primary key.

Answer (score 1):

How about using something like this. This assigns generic `row_number()` to each value in the table and then you join on that row number value:

```
select i.[item no],
  i.name,
  l.location
from
(
  select [item no], name,
    row_number() over(partition by [item no] order by name) rn
  from item
) i
full outer join
(
  select [item no], location,
    row_number() over(partition by [item no] order by location) rn
  from locations
) l
  on i.rn = l.rn
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4f29b/1)

Result from your sample data is:

```
| ITEM NO |  NAME |  LOCATION |
-------------------------------
|       1 | Name1 | Location1 |
|       1 | Name2 | Location2 |
|       1 | Name3 |    (null) |
```

Comment: I'll try out this solution and let you know how it goes.